# How to make polygons from interpolated points?

Tags: qgis, geometry-conversion, inverse-distance-weighted

My goal is to make a shapefile with polygons for variable rate fertilizer application within a farm field.

I have a point shapefile with soil sample values (pH, P, K and so on) and a line/polygon file with field borders. IDW is recognizes as a suitable interpolation method for soil samples. I have gotten as far as having the interpolated points as a raster file and I have experimented with the "Contour" function to make a suitable classification.

I'm looking for a solution in QGIS to convert/make/bake the classified raster in to polygons, and clip the results to the field border. Does any one have a suitable solution for this using QGIS?

Edit:

I don't know if my question is clear enough. To illustrate my goal the attached picture shows how I need my final shapefile to be.

[image: Picture illustrating the final result I'm after. The points are interpolated, clipped to the field border and then (some how) the classified raster is converted to a polygon shapefile.]

The picture illustrates the final result I'm after. The points are interpolated, clipped to the field border and then (some how) the classified raster is converted to a polygon shapefile.

Comment: Have you tried _Raster_ > _Conversion_ > _Polygonize_?

Answer (score 1):

@Joseph is right. Use the polygonize tool to make the raster into a polygon. Choose the option to write the raster values to an attribute column (ie: dn). This will allow you to dissolve the polygon on dn values that are the same, which will result in a cleaner looking file. With your input polygon that is a field boundary, use the clip tool (vectors/geoprocessing) to clip your rasterized polygon.

Comment: Thank's! This is rely helpful. The polygonizer tool classifies the raster values from 0 to 26 in intervals of 1. Is there a way to change the interval?

Comment: Can you comment more on what you mean, or what you would like to have as an outcome.

Comment: My rasterfile has values from 0 to 26. I'd like the final polygonized file to have polygons with intervals of 0,5. The Raster to Vector function only makes intervals between the polygons of 1,0.

Comment: You could add a new column to your polygon and do a reclassification based on your needs